# How do you export or release a Mac OS X program made in Xcode? Program does not load on other computers

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, release, software-distribution

I made a program in Xcode, being a simple calculator that takes a first number, and a second number, and then either adds,subtracts,multiplies, or divides depending on the radio button. I build and run and the program comes up and works fine. When I went to show my friends on their macs, when you double click on the program the program pops in the tray for like .05 seconds and then disappears and we never can actually run the program. It still works perfect however on my computer.

What am I doing wrong? How can I take the program I made, and run it on different macs? I have the release set to 10.5 but the active SDK to 10.6. It runs in both 10.5 and 10.6 simulators. One friend has 10.6.3 like me and the other has 10.5.x(cant remember the last part).

To get the app, I changed from debug to release and set active SDK to 10.5. Then in the release folder I found the app and sent that over iChat.

I feel this will be a problem in the future if I ever make a legit application to distribute.

Thank you!

**I uploaded the release version to show you better what I mean.**

http://www.filefront.com/16472557/Mac%20App%20Test.zip

Comment: To get clues to whats actually going wrong try running it from a terminal and watch the output. Also take a look at `syslog`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: There is a utility called "Console.app" which is intalled on every Macintosh.  If you have this running when you try to open your app, you should see any errors encountered that stop it running.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention:  Console.app is in /Applications/Utilities

Comment: I don't know If adding a comment to my question will reopen it but I'm still having the same problem. I made another program a quick label saying I'm working, and that won't work on other peoples computers either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to turn off ZeroLink so that all the code you need is included in the executable.  You can do that in the Linking build settings collection.

ZeroLink should have been turned off when you switched to release. I'm not sure why it didn't, but you should be able to do it manually.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Sadly though, when I go into projects -> edit project settings -> then the build tab and then down to linking, I don't see anything about ZeroLink. I searched zero in the search area and that found nothing either.

I'm using Xcode 3.2.2.

Comment: I uploaded my release app to filefront to give a better idea on to what is happening.

Comment: Your app runs fine on my iMac(10.6.3).  I'm not sure what the problem might be now.

Comment: Hmm well I fooled around with it and then built again. I'm gonna try it on my friends computers when I get a chance, and if it doesn't work I'll post here again.

Thanks a ton for your help as it defiantly lead to some insight as I researched zerolink further.

Comment: Bummer, I tried a newer one with my friend and it didn't work yet I tried the one I uploaded as you said it worked and it did. Now I don't know what I did to make it work and now I have a non working one. Only thing I really did different is zip it lol

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 when you don't zip an app and export it, the finder destroys the permissions architecture inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Walkthrough: Press ctrl + icon -> open to prevent unsigned security handling for this app.